# How to aggregate while breaking up an array to allow entry to count multiple times?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

So I'm using the IMDB movies and reviews data set and an example of the data looks like:

```
{
  movie_id: tt1982833,
  genre: ["Action", "Adventure", "Sci-Fi"],
  ...
}
```

What I'm trying to do is count the number of movies that fit into each genre, but I'm having a tough time breaking up the genre's into individual elements, instead of the array as a whole. Currently I have:

```
db.movies.aggregate([
  {$group: {"_id": "$genre", "count": {$sum: 1}}}
])
```

How can I change this to account for a movie being in multiple genres?

Comment: [$unwind (aggregation)](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/#unwind-aggregation) good starting point with official documentation  https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/#unwind-aggregation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$unwind` is the operator you need.

> **$unwind**
>
> Deconstructs an array field from the input documents to output
>   a document for each element. Each output document is the input
>   document with the value of the array field replaced by the element.

Below example should work.

```
db.movies.aggregate([     
    {$unwind : "$genre"},
    {$group: {"_id": "$genre", "count": {$sum: 1}}}
])
```